# What the reason behind untheorized error when calling API from api connect?

Tags: apiconnect

I'm trying to deploy an API using api connect.
I have create API, product, subscription, catalog;
then I have client id , client secret,
then I call  my API it was working and the data  returned, then I have changed client id and client secret but the below error was generated:

```
{

     "httpCode": "401",

     "httpMessage": "Unauthorized",

     "moreInformation": "Invalid client id or secret."
}
```

Note: I pass client id and secret id as headers as below:

```
X-IBM-Client-Id = 
X-IBM-Client-Secret=
```

what else do I have to do?

I tried to call the API after changing the credential but received the mentioned error.

Comment: the error is pretty clear, you are passing Invalid client id or secret, make sure new new client id and secret is on the server side, did you change it there too?